# discord bot automaticly assign role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

why after i run this code nothing happend, can you fix it for me? it bassed on discord.js v14

the code :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, // Required to track member joins
  ],
});

const token = 'token';
const roleIdToAdd = '1038099433595867246'; // Replace with the ID of the role you want to assign
const logChannelId = '1150425856322314330'; // Replace with the ID of the log channel

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
  // Check if the member is the bot itself
  if (member.user) return;

  // Assign the specified role to the member
  try {
    const role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(roleIdToAdd);
    if (role) {
      await member.roles.add(role);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error assigning the role:', error);
  }

  // Send a log message to the designated log channel
  const logChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(logChannelId);
  if (logChannel) {
    logChannel.send(`User ${member.user.tag} added/invited the bot to the server.`);
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

I want my bot to automatically assign a role to someone who invites/adds my bot to their server and automatically send a log when someone adds/invites my bot to their server

Comment: Any error? Does the bot have `Manage roles` permission?

Comment: `member.user` will always be truthy and it will always return from the function. Maybe you want `member.user.bot` to check if the user bot and if it's bot return and don't give the role.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since `member.user` returns a User type, this is truthy in any case
2. If you want to check if a Bot has been invited, you need to use the `guildCreate` event
   (Actually, the Discord API does not provide information about the user who invited the bot, so you have to give up posting information about the user who invited the bot)

so finnaly code is

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, // Required to track member joins
  ],
});

const token = 'token';
const roleIdToAdd = '1038099433595867246'; // Replace with the ID of the role you want to assign
const logChannelId = '1150425856322314330'; // Replace with the ID of the log channel

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
  // Check if the member is the bot itself
  if (member.user.id === client.user.id) return;

  // Assign the specified role to the member
  try {
    const role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(roleIdToAdd);
    if (role) {
      await member.roles.add(role);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error assigning the role:', error);
  }
});

client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
  // Send a log message to the designated log channel
  const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(logChannelId);
  if (logChannel) {
    logChannel.send(`This bot has been added to \`${guild.name
    }\` .`);
  }
});

client.login(token);
```